# Module not found if installing a package in global with pnpm

Tags: pnpm

I am trying to install `prettier` with `pnpm install prettier -g`, and when I tried to run it in the terminal, it gives me the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/hugosum/pnpm-global/5/node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

When I do `which prettier`, it gives me `/usr/local/bin/prettier`. How can I further debug and solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by cleaning up duplicating binary in `/usr/local/bin`